# SparkSession readText file with custom logic

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to read spark text file into `JavaRDD`, Below code works perfectly fine

```
JavaRDD rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext().textFile(filePath, 100).toJavaRDD();
```

I want to apply some conditional reading in this function of `textFile`

For example:

if the content of text file is as below (note this is simplified example)

```
1
2
2
3
4
4
```

I want to be able to look ahead or look back and eliminate duplicates based on some logic.

I don't want to do it at the time of processing rdd. I want to be able to do it at the time of reading text file itself.

Comment: There's no public API for such low-level functionality. `sc.textFile` isn't even aware of data types other than string. Also, remember that this is a very high-level method, which goes over hadoop FS API to different underlying file system types, with very few assumptions... Rather create files strategically if this is very important to your jobs.

Comment: If the logic to apply is "per file" and files are not too big, an option could be `wholeTextFile`. Otherwise, we'd need more context and the volume of data to handle.

Answer (score 0):

As Spark goes through an optimizer. spark will actually perform the  transformations and the filter for each line as it is read, it will not need to put all the data in memory.

My advice is to use the filter operation. Furthermore you can [persist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) resulting RDD to avoid recomputation.